# Return taken fields before submitting to the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. The following user input for categories are being returned in comma separated values. business, home-repair, flooring.

```
    // Insert tile tags 
    $data      = array();
    $tag_title = $request->tag_title;

    $data = explode(',', $tag_title);

    foreach($data as $newTag) {

        $tag = new Tag;
        $tag->tag_title = $newTag;
        $tag->save();

    }
```

The problem is, the second category **home-repair** already exists in the table which is required to be unique and is causing an obvious constraint thus preventing any of the code that follows to fail.

How can I first test to see if any of these categories/tags are taken and then return to the user which are taken when adding a new tag?

Or would the better approach be, in my mind, is to have the records checked and only insert new ones that don't already exist in the table. Seems alot cleaner. Can this be achieved in Laravel?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO` might be what you're looking for, not sure how it's done in Laraval unfortunately.

Comment: did you try with `firstOrFail()` ? - `try { Model::where(conditions)->firstOrFail() } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) { Model::create(data) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can use firstOrCreate...

```
foreach($data as $newTag) {

    $temp = Tag::firstOrCreate(array('tag_title'=>$newTag));

}
```

...so if a Tag with tag_title doesn't exist yet it will be created.

Comment: Also don't forget to add `tag_title` to the `$fillable` array in your model (if you haven't already)